# Deploy WebJobs using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-webjobs

I was following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs#convertlink) blog post to deploy my existing console app to web jobs.But, I'm unable to find right-click, "Add > Existing Project as Azure WebJob"  option in Visual Studio 2015. I did install the new Azure SDK bits. Just wondering if this future has been deprecated ?

Answer (score 0):

The option is still there. But please do note that this is only supported on regular ASP.NET projects. So if you are using ASP.NET Core, that option is not available at this time.

Comment: Ah, that might be the reason why I'm not seeing this option. Both my console app and website are using the new .Net Core bits. 

Just wondering, is there any way to deploy .Net Core Console app from VS 2015

Comment: Might be best as a separate question, since this one is more focuses on whether the current support you read about still exists (which it does). That being said, see [this post](https://blog.decayingcode.com/post/creating-.net-core-console-webjobs-on-an-asp.net-core-azure-webapp/).